Downporting C++17 to C++14: Cannot call member function without object
I need to convert a C++17 project down to C++14 because I'm targetting a platform whose gcc doesn't support anything newer than C++14. I was able to adapt 99% of the code so that it compiles in C++14 mode but there's one thing where I don't know how to adapt it for C++14. It's this code:
sptr<Box> MatrixAtom::createBox(Env& env) {
  if (_matType == MatrixType::smallMatrix) {
    return env.withStyle(TexStyle::script, [this](auto& script) { return createBoxInner(script); });
  } 
  return createBoxInner(env);
}

(full code here)
When compiling this as C++14, gcc returns the following error:
lib/atom/atom_matrix.cpp: In instantiation of 'microtex::MatrixAtom::createBox(microtex::Env&)::<lambda(auto:1&)> [with auto:1 = microtex::Env]':
lib/env/env.h:196:60:   required by substitution of 'template<class F> decltype (f((*(microtex::Env*)this))) microtex::Env::withStyle(microtex::TexStyle, F&&) [with F = microtex::MatrixAtom::createBox(microtex::Env&)::<lambda(auto:1&)>]'
lib/atom/atom_matrix.cpp:597:99:   required from here
lib/atom/atom_matrix.cpp:597:98: error: cannot call member function 'microtex::sptr<microtex::Box> microtex::MatrixAtom::createBoxInner(microtex::Env&)' without object
     return env.withStyle(TexStyle::script, [this](auto& script) { return createBoxInner(script); });
                                                                                              
lib/atom/atom_matrix.cpp: In member function 'virtual microtex::sptr<microtex::Box> microtex::MatrixAtom::createBox(microtex::Env&)':
lib/atom/atom_matrix.cpp:597:25: error: could not convert '(& env)->microtex::Env::withStyle<microtex::MatrixAtom::createBox(microtex::Env&)::<lambda(auto:1&)> >((microtex::TexStyle)4, <lambda closure object>microtex::MatrixAtom::createBox(microtex::Env&)::<lambda(auto:1&)>{((microtex::MatrixAtom*)this)})' from 'void' to 'microtex::sptr<microtex::Box> {aka std::shared_ptr<microtex::Box>}'
     return env.withStyle(TexStyle::script, [this](auto& script) { return createBoxInner(script); });
            ~~~~~~~~~~~~~^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
In file included from lib/env/units.h:4:0,
                 from lib/core/parser.h:5,
                 from lib/core/formula.h:7,
                 from lib/atom/atom_matrix.cpp:7:
lib/env/env.h: In instantiation of 'decltype (f((*(microtex::Env*)this))) microtex::Env::withStyle(microtex::TexStyle, F&&) [with F = microtex::MatrixAtom::createBox(microtex::Env&)::<lambda(auto:1&)>; decltype (f((*(microtex::Env*)this))) = void]':
lib/atom/atom_matrix.cpp:597:99:   required from here
lib/env/env.h:199:26: error: 'void result' has incomplete type
     auto result = f(*this);
                          ^
lib/env/env.h:201:12: error: return-statement with a value, in function returning 'void' [-fpermissive]
     return result; 

Does anybody know how I could rewrite the code to make it compile with C++14?
Thanks!

Try this: return this->createBoxInner(script);
